# heroku django south does not appear to use migrations

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-south

I'm having trouble with Django south migrations. It may be related to how we've laid our project out but it was working previously, and it works fine locally.

I pushed new code last night that contained a migration in `my_app` app. So in my local environment...

```
$ ./manage.py migrate --list
socialaccount
(*) 0001_initial
(*) 0002_genericmodels
(*) 0003_auto__add_unique_socialaccount_uid_provider
(*) 0004_add_sites
(*) 0005_set_sites
(*) 0006_auto__del_field_socialapp_site
(*) 0007_auto__add_field_socialapp_client_id
(*) 0008_client_id
(*) 0009_auto__add_field_socialtoken_expires_at
(*) 0010_auto__chg_field_socialtoken_token
(*) 0011_auto__chg_field_socialtoken_token
payments
(*) 0001_initial
users
(*) 0001_initial
my_app
(*) 0001_initial
(*) 0002_auto__add_organizerapplication
```

In heroku, it doesn't recognize my_app as an app with migrations. When I attempt to migrate that app....

```
$ heroku run my_app/manage.py migrate my_app --app=my_app

Running my_app/manage.py migrate my_app attached to terminal... up, run.5016
The app 'my_app' does not appear to use migrations.
./manage.py migrate [appname] [migrationname|zero] [--all] [--list] [--skip] [--merge] [--no-initial-data] [--fake] [--db-dry-run] [--database=dbalias]
```

If I list the migrations, you'll notice my_app isn't listed...

```
$ heroku run my_app/manage.py migrate --list --app=my_app

Running my_app/manage.py migrate --list attached to terminal... up, run.8264

socialaccount
(*) 0001_initial
(*) 0002_genericmodels
(*) 0003_auto__add_unique_socialaccount_uid_provider
(*) 0004_add_sites
(*) 0005_set_sites
(*) 0006_auto__del_field_socialapp_site
(*) 0007_auto__add_field_socialapp_client_id
(*) 0008_client_id
(*) 0009_auto__add_field_socialtoken_expires_at
(*) 0010_auto__chg_field_socialtoken_token
(*) 0011_auto__chg_field_socialtoken_token
payments
(*) 0001_initial
users
(*) 0001_initial
```

I'm not sure it's relevant but `my_app` is listed in my `INSTALLED_APPS` when I check.

UPDATE

The issue was that this particular migrations dir was missing `__init__.py.` Running commands like `convert_to_south` through Heroku don't impact this as local file changes don't stick. Pushing the repo again with that file got the migrations recognized. I then just had to fake the first migration and I was good.

Comment: I may have found the solution. It appears the my_app/migrations dir that was pushed to heroku is missing a __init__.py file. Running convert_to_south will create that, however, those files can't be put in place using heroku command line. I believe the solution, still to test out, is to get the __init__ in place and push that change.

Comment: Would you please move your update to an answer and accept it so this is no longer listed as an unanswered question?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have a init.py file in the migrations folder of the app you want to migrate.  South will work locally, but not in production on heroku.  Simply copy an init.py file from one of your apps, and put it into the migrations folder for the app you are getting the error for.  Push that change to production, and then migrate.

Comment: Pstrazzulla is correct, if no __init__.py is detected, south won't be able to tell the app wanna to be managed by it.